# How to make ActiveMQ notify on reaching memory or persistence threshold

Tags: activemq-classic

In our setup, we would like to get notifications when slow consumers make ActiveMQ broker to run out of memory (or get close to running out of memory), and later when persistence (e.g., KahaDB) reaches some limits.

So far I only found `sendFailIfNoSpace` setting which will cause exception on a producer side. Any other way to get these notifications (for example, as an advisory messages on a separate topic) for monitoring purposes? Thresholds could be less than a physical limit to provide a timely warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The broker can send out some advisory messages when certain usage monitors are full, which is [documented](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) at the ActiveMQ site.  You can also [monitor](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html) some broker information via its JMX MBeans, one of them is the Health View MBean which will give you some data on the current health of the broker.

Good idea to look at all the info on the broker [monitoring](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to monitor ActiveMQ memory/store usage is to use ActiveMQ [Statistics Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html), which must be enabled explicitly.

ActiveMQ will send response with stats (including memory/temp/store usage) to the `replyTo` destination for messages sent to `ActiveMQ.Statistics.Broker` queue.

Please note this plug-in is not available in releases prior to 5.3.